# psutil module in python not updating

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7, psutil

I am trying to make an alarm system to tell me if my charger is in or not but once I run the script the output doesn't update. I am working on windows. here is my code:

```
import psutil

battery = psutil.sensors_battery()

def test():
    to = battery.power_plugged
    if to:
        print("good")
        to = battery.power_plugged

    if not to:
        print("bad")
        to = battery.power_plugged

while True:
    test()
```

Comment: You have to call the function(`psutil.sensors_battery()`) inside test

Comment: `psutil.sensors_battery()` returns a named tuple. You may have to call it again within your loop to refresh that tuple.